# Smarty absolute path

Tags: php, smarty, absolute-path

I am using smarty, and I want to have link to file kategorija.php with one argument.  Why I get this strange link in the browser?

```
http://localhost/ljekarna/%60http://localhost/ljekarna/kategorija.php?id=1
```

This is my code with absolute path

[image]

And this is the result

[image]

Comment: Please don't include images of your code. Just include it as text in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a backtick (`) before http that shouldn't be there